# what's wrong with defining a 2d vector as a data member of a class?

Tags: c++

I am coding a class which has a 2d vector in its private data members named board,
I have defined the vector like this in the header file of class:
World.h:

```
vector <vector<Cell> > board;
vector <Cell> columns;//Cell is name of another class
```

World.cpp:

```
columns.resize(number_of_columns);
for(int i=0;i<number_of_lines;i++) board.push_back(number_of_columns);
```

and after this i tried to access the members of the vector in this way:

```
board[i][j]
```

i had errors which said

> Error  error C2065: 'board' : undeclared identifier

what's wrong with it?

---

more of code added:
World.h:

```
class World {
    private :
    bool ring;
    int lines, columns ;
    vector <Cell> columns;
        vector <vector<Cell> > board;
public:
    //blahhhh
    };
```

World.cpp:

```
World:: World(int l , int c)
{
    columns.resize(c);
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++) board.push_back(columns);
}
```

i this function it doesn't know what is board! and have a error because of this.

Comment: is World.h included in World.cpp?

Comment: I can only assume `board` isn't in scope for some reason, but I can't say why without more of the code.

Comment: Can you post the full code? If board is a private data member I'm curious as to how you are accessing it.

Comment: There's also a slight possibility that you didn't include `<vector>` and qualify the `std` namespace somewhere (which is really bad to do in the global scope of headers) and then just skipped down past the first error.

Comment: Is the function from where the error is generated qualified with the class name?

Comment: Is the constructor `World::World()` declared in the header file declaration of `class World`?

Comment: Not an answer but general comments: 1 - use `size_type` or `size_t` for the indices of the containers instead of `int`. 2 - *Don't* qualify the namespace in world.h, and use `std::vector` instead of `vector`. For your specific problem, I'd say that can't be.

Comment: That code does not match the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because of forgetting of entering : using namespace std;

Comment: You better not use that in your header files though, or you'll flood the global namespace with all the stuff from std whenever this header file is included.